# Determine if augmented system has how many solutions

Tags: matrices

*Note: I'm not sure about the syntax for augmented system so if anyone can help me edit that would be great, but for now I'll just use preformatted text.*

Determine, with reasons, those values of a (if any) such that the augmented system has

- a unique solution
- no solution
- infinitely many solutions

[image]

The trouble I have here is getting it into row-echelon form. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract row 1 from row 2. Subtract $a$ times row 1 from row 3. Subtract appropriate multiple of row 2 from row 3. You're now in upper triangular form, which should do.